# Delphi generics TObjectList<T> inheritance

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2010

I want to create a `TObjectList<T>` descendant to handle common functionality between object lists in my app. Then I want to further descend from that new class to introduce additional functionality when needed. I cannot seem to get it working using more than 1 level of inheritance. I probably need to understand generics a little bit more, but I've search high and low for the correct way to do this without success. Here is my code so far:

```
unit edGenerics;

interface

uses
  Generics.Collections;

type

  TObjectBase = class
  public
    procedure SomeBaseFunction;
  end;

  TObjectBaseList<T: TObjectBase> = class(TObjectList<T>)
  public
    procedure SomeOtherBaseFunction;
  end;

  TIndexedObject = class(TObjectBase)
  protected
    FIndex: Integer;
  public
    property Index: Integer read FIndex write FIndex;
  end;

  TIndexedObjectList<T: TIndexedObject> = class(TObjectBaseList<T>)
  private
    function GetNextAutoIndex: Integer;
  public
    function Add(AObject: T): Integer;
    function ItemByIndex(AIndex: Integer): T;
    procedure Insert(AIndex: Integer; AObject: T);
  end;

  TCatalogueItem = class(TIndexedObject)
  private
    FID: integer;
  public
    property ID: integer read FId write FId;
  end;

  TCatalogueItemList = class(TIndexedObjectList<TCatalogueItem>)
  public
    function GetRowById(AId: Integer): Integer;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Math;

{ TObjectBase }

procedure TObjectBase.SomeBaseFunction;
begin
end;

{ TObjectBaseList<T> }

procedure TObjectBaseList<T>.SomeOtherBaseFunction;
begin
end;

{ TIndexedObjectList }

function TIndexedObjectList<T>.Add(AObject: T): Integer;
begin
  AObject.Index := GetNextAutoIndex;
  Result := inherited Add(AObject);
end;

procedure TIndexedObjectList<T>.Insert(AIndex: Integer; AObject: T);
begin
  AObject.Index := GetNextAutoIndex;
  inherited Insert(AIndex, AObject);
end;

function TIndexedObjectList<T>.ItemByIndex(AIndex: Integer): T;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := Default(T);
  while (Count > 0) and (I < Count) and (Result = Default(T)) do
    if Items[I].Index = AIndex then
      Result := Items[I]
    else
      Inc(I);
end;

function TIndexedObjectList<T>.GetNextAutoIndex: Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
    Result := Max(Result, Items[I].Index);
  Inc(Result);
end;

{ TCatalogueItemList }

function TCatalogueItemList.GetRowById(AId: Integer): Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := -1;
  for I := 0 to Pred(Self.Count) do
    if Self.Items[I].Id = AId then
    begin
      Result := I;
      Break;
    end;
end;

end.
/////// ERROR HAPPENS HERE ////// ???? why is beyond me
```

It appears that the following declaration:

```
>>> TCatalogueItemList = class(TIndexedObjectList<TCatalogueItem>) <<<<
```

causes the following compiler error:

> [DCC Error] edGenerics.pas(106): E2010 Incompatible types:
>   'TCatalogueItem' and 'TIndexedObject'

**However** the compiler shows the error at the END of the compiled unit (line 106), not on the declaration itself, which does not make any sense to me...

Basically the idea is that I have a generic list descending from TObjectList that I can extend with new functionality on an as needs basis. Any help with this would be GREAT!!!

I should add, using Delphi 2010.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice (since you have it available) if you would point out the actual portion of the code causing the error. It's much easier than expecting us to count or copy/paste into an editor. A simple comment like `// error happens here` or `//this is line 106` would suffice.

Comment: added further explanation to the question body

Comment: Shouldn't the `TIndexedObjectList<T: TIndexedObject>` descend from `TObjectBaseList<T: TObjectBase>` and not from `TObjectList<T>` as in your current code?

Comment: Yes it should thanks for picking that up. However after making the correction to the declaration, it is exactly the same compile error as before.

Comment: @Ken: The XE3 IDE locates the error on the last line of the file (after the final end.) No line number is provided in the error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your error is in the type casting, and the compiler error is OK (but it fails to locate the correct file in my Delphi XE3).

Your ItemByIndex method is declared:

```
TIndexedObjectList<T>.ItemByIndex(AIndex: Integer): T;
```

But then you have the line:

```
Result := TIndexedObject(nil);
```

This is fine for the *parent* class `TIndexedObjectList`, where the result of the function is of type `TIndexedObject`, **but is not OK for the descendant class** `TCatalogueItemList`, where the result of the function is of the type `TCatalogueItem`.

As you may know, a `TCatalogueItem` instance is assignment compatible with a `TIndexedObject` variable, but the opposite is not true. It translates to something like this:

```
function TCatalogueItemList.ItemByIndex(AIndex: Integer): TCatalogueItem;
begin
  Result := TIndexedObject(nil);  //did you see the problem now?
```

To initialize the result to a nil value, you can call the Default() pseudo-function, like this:

```
Result := Default(T);
```

In Delphi XE or greater, the solution is also generic. Rather than type-casting the result as a fixed `TIndexedObjectList` class, you apply a generic type casting use the T type

```
Result := T(nil);
//or 
Result := T(SomeOtherValue);
```

But, in this specific case, **type-casting a `nil` constant is not needed**, since `nil` is a special value that is assignment compatible with any reference, so you just have to replace the line with:

```
Result := nil;
```

And it will compile, and hopefully work as you expect.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. It _almost_ works, but the line: `Result := nil` causes a compile error `Incompatible types: 'T' and 'Pointer'`. That's why I previously type-cast this to a TIndexedObject. How do I set the Result for a generic type to nil or the generic equivalent?

Comment: In XE3 it works, but if your compiler requires a casting, use the Generic one: `Result := T(nil);`, as said in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but unfortunately in Delphi 2010 the statement `Result := T(nil);` creates an `Invalid typecast` error. So neither approach seems to work in Delphi 2010. Interestingly if I comment out the line altogether it compiles without error. I'll test this further to see if it returns nil when an item is not in the list.

Comment: In Delphi 2010 (and maybe later?), the correct way to initialise a generic type for a function result is `Result := Default(T);`. That seems to works correctly for the function above.

Comment: @Rick and jachguate: thanks for `Default(T)`. Learned something new.

Comment: @MarjanVenema You've not been paying attention. We cover `Default(T)` every other week here!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: oh dear, caught out am I? Been very busy with other stuff, don't pay as much attention to SO as I have been...